# Flicker During Repaint of Component in JScrollPane

Tags: java, graphics

Background:

The application I'm writing utilizes a custom component (which extends JPanel) for visualizing data. The component is placed inside of a JScrollPane and a MouseListener is used to monitor mouse wheel movement. When wheel movement is detected a zoom effect is created by fractionally increasing or decreasing the size of the component using setSize() and setPreferredSize().

Problem:

When the scrolling rate is too fast the component contained by the JScrollPane will flicker during repaint.

Attempted Workaround:

1. Setting a more refined repaint region does not help since the entire component contained in the JScrollPane is being resized.
2. Setting the JScrollPane to double buffered does not have a noticeable effect.

One thought I had is to limit the rate at the the wheel movements can be applied. Any suggestions for implementing this?

Other suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you doing all of your repaints and updating of the component on the event dispatch thread?